# I want to perform build automation using python, and it should be cross platform. Is python a good choice?

Tags: python

I would like to automate nightly builds using python. I am new to python and will need guidance from the programmers who can help me.

Comment: It's a brilliant choice. It's installed by default on most unix-like systems. It easily performs all the functions of a shell with increased type safety and portability.

Comment: Your title "I want to ... using Python... is Python a good choice" is silly.  If you're going to use Python, why ask?  If you're going to ask, why assume you're using Python?

Answer (score 1):

Python is a nice language for build automation. There are two python based build systems, [Scons](http://scons.org/) and [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/), that will ease the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

If your project have already any build system (automake, cmake, msbuild, ant, maven.. you name it), you can use some ready CI solution. There is some choice here, including one written in python (buildbot: http://trac.buildbot.net/), but I'd suggest to set up Jenkins: http://jenkins-ci.org/. It's very good, easy to use, quite scalable, cross-platform, cross-language, build-system-agnostic, extensible CI system.

If not, then you should start with applying some existing build system.

Comment: Yes the installations are done using jenkins. But from autoamtion developer point of view I need to automate the release builds and make sure they are installed on the system automatically without any user intervention.

Comment: In this case you should provide more details about your deployment setup. In general, most of scenarios are manageable with Jenkins (for example we're doing deployment of mobile application installation files from windows-based build machine to linux-based web server - nothing fancy, just a windows shell script with putty's scp done after successful build on stable branch).

Comment: Well the builds are on the shared drive and I need to access the build on the shared drive.Install the build and then run the automated test suite across windows,mac and linux.

Comment: You can write in in python, but I think it would be more efficient to write it with windows/bash/osx shell scripting.

Split the job into chained (upstream/downstream or by using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) jobs: one for getting files from shared drive (probably separate scrips for win/linux/osx, because of different ways of accesing network shares), one for automated tests executed on slave nodes for each target system.

Answer (score 0):

`Python` is much better choice,since `Python` is used extensively in `youtube` to do automation work,`Python` is also used in `robotics`,so `python` is right choice, it would be much easier for us to help if you can share what type of automation you are speaking about.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Well basically I want to use python for automating installations of the software build on windows,mac and linux.

Comment: You can definitely do it,here is an example by me ,take look at it.You can email me for any help,http://kracekumar.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/automount-partitions-in-gnulinux-using-python/